# Can't install engish_words in flutter depedencies

Tags: android-studio, dart, dependencies, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

i am running this code

`dependencies:`
`flutter`:
`sdk: flutter`
`english_words:^3.1.5`
and having this  [image: this is the snippet of error i am getting in terminal]

I've tried it on VS Code and Android Studio 
***Please answer me as fast as i can***

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you made a line break between english_words: and ^3.1.5, when you write it in one line it should work.

Comment: no actually when i saw it in terminal it appears to be in next line but in actual code it's in same line

Comment: Can you post your whole pubspec.yaml so we can have a look at it?